# How do I redirect the output of a Invoke-Command -AsJob to verbose stream?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a command on a pool of remote servers using `Invoke-Command` as a job.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServerList -ScriptBlock $remoteScript -AsJob
```

The output is a list of jobs with status:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
35     Job35           RemoteJob       Running       True            remoteserv1          Hostname
37     Job37           RemoteJob       Running       True            remoteserv2          Hostname
39     Job39           RemoteJob       Running       True            remoteserv3          Hostname
```

How can I redirect this output to the verbose stream, so that this list only shows when I run my powershell script with `-verbose` ?

Adding `| Write-Verbose` to that command prints:

```
VERBOSE: System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob
```

Comment: `| Out-String | Write-Verbose`

Comment: @PetSerAl - You are the king of drive by answers in the comments section.  I am going to start posting your comments as my own answer if you don't post them as answers ;)

Comment: @JasonBoyd If you not just copy my comment, but also provide explanation and solve some possible issues, which I do not take in account in my comments (like extra newline in this one), then I am perfectly fine with that.